# iframe within a webview does not allow you to use drag and drop

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Following the sample for embedding an `iframe` which loads an external page (loaded from localhost) - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions#option-1-use-asexternaluri

I noticed that my drag and drop events are not correctly passed over into the iframe. In the webview, all works fine, same on the iframe, but not within the contents from the iframe.

For instance, if I register the following event listeners in the HTML for the webview:

```
window.addEventListener('message', (e) => { console.log('webview message', e.data) });
window.addEventListener('dragenter', () => { console.log('webview dragenter') });
window.addEventListener('dragover', () => { console.log('webview dragover') });
window.addEventListener('drop', () => { console.log('webview drop') });
```

It works as expected:

[image: logging]

When this is added within the page loaded from the iframe, it isn't triggered. Contents are loaded fine, and all other behavior, except for the drag and drop functionality.

Comment: Hey @elio-struyf, did you solve this problem? I have a similar one where where I have a webview in my vscode plugin using an iframe. This iframe does also contain another iframe, and some drag and drop interactions do not work (some of them do). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi @protozoo, nope, never solved this. Also opened an issue, but unfortunately, this is a limitation of the webview/iframe, as VS Code has its own message handlers. The advice was not to use iframes.

Comment: Hi @elio-struyf, could you provide a link to the issue? Did you write in your blog about this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with WebView 2, although I was using [Tauri](https://tauri.app/), I had the same problem that events were not triggered inside iframe when I was dragging items over it.

I solved this issue by adding an additional `dropzone` attribute to an `<iframe>` element itself. Hopefully it works for you as werll.